# Attaching a TextEdit file to Python

Tags: python, sql, attachment, textedit

I am creating a database but I cannot figure out how to attach a TextEdit file to my python code. Here is my code at the moment:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("Weather.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Hydro_RAINFALL(
wind VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
temp VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
precipitation VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
humidity VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL);
''')

cursor.execute('''
ATTACH DATABASE "Hydro-RAINFALL-2.py" as "Hydro-RAINFALL";
''')
```

`"Hydro-RAINFALL-2.py"` is the name of the TextEdit file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Huh, the only **TextEdit** I know is a simple text file editor. *"TextEdit files"* are just normal text files. Your file has `py` extension which makes us think it is a normal text file with python code in it??? Can you show the contents of this file, or tell more about the format? How did you create the file? `ATTACH DATABASE` should be used with sqlite databases, not with normal text files created by **TextEdit**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a TextEdit file is not a thing; all TextEdit does is edit text files such as python scripts or `.txt` files. From what I understand from your question what you're looking for is:

```
open('Hydro-RAINFALL-2.py').read()
```

if not I'm not sure whether I can help you as this question is worded quite poorly.